# Visual Studio 2017 opening edmx file cause HRESULT: 0x80029C4A error

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dll, visual-studio-2017, edmx-designer

I am trying to open edmx file with ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer but I am getting the below error:

```
Cannot load 'C:\MyUserName\source\repos\MyProject\MyModel.edmx': Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))
```

I have tried answers to similar questions:

- Repairing Visual Studio from Visual Studio Installer
- Re-installing Visual Studio
- Removing and re-installing Entity Framework 6 tools
- Running visual studio as admin and clean-rebuild project

But none of them worked. Also, I can not re-install EntityFramework from the NuGet Package Manager or Console, the same error pops up. Adding a new ADO.NET Model is not possible either due to this error. This problem is not only occurring in this project but all of them so I guess it is directly related to Visual Studio.

How can I fix this issue? Thanks!

I am using .NET 4.8, EntityFramework 6.4.4

Comment: Hi @wenbingeng-MSFT, Thanks for your answer! I have switched to Visual Studio 2022 and everything works, Actually, I don't want to mess things up again by modifying the registry.

Comment: Hi, you can share your solution and mark it to help more people

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

1. Delete the registry

(1) Win+r opens the run window and enters regedit to run the registry editor.

(2) Find the registry of version 1.xxx

[image]

2. Uninstall Visual Studio
3. Reinstall Visual Studio